# SVG Filter - feColorMatrix has non-linear color

Tags: svg, svg-filters, color-space, colormatrix

I'm trying to use an SVG filter to offset and fill the shape with a specific color. To adjust the color I'm using `<feColorMatrix>`. I understand the color matrix uses clamp values for color, so I calculated the clamp values by taking the R, G, B values (0-255) and divided them by 256.

The issue is, this produced a much lighter color. I then tried it with a simple 0.5 and then color picked the result. I would expect a value of rgb(128,128,128) #808080 or at least something close, but it came out as a shocking rgb(187,187,187) #bbbbbb.

```
<filter id="midgrey">
    <feColorMatrix values="
        0 0 0 0 0.5
        0 0 0 0 0.5
        0 0 0 0 0.5
        0 0 0 1 0">
    </feColorMatrix>
</filter>
```

Obviously there's some kind of conversion going on here. After a bit of testing, the conversion definitely appears non-linear – some kind of exponential remapping.

**Question #1: Where is this defined in the [specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/)? I looked and couldn't find anything other than a [brief mention of filters using the sRGB color space](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty). Is this the reason?**

> color-interpolation-filters has no affect for Filter Functions. Filter Functions must operate in the sRGB color space.

**Question #2: How can I convert from RGB triplets to this color scale such that the resulting color matches in RGB space?**

**Question #3: Perhaps this is the wrong way to convert color with SVG filters. Is there a different way to flood-fill a shape with a specific color?**

(Note, it would still be nice to have answers to all three questions, even if an answer is provided for just #3)

TIA!

Comment: Q1, yes, Q2 [see the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ColorInterpolationProperties) Q3 [feFlood](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feFloodElement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, firstly, don't believe everything you read in the specs - especially when they're not
at least a Candidate Recommendation. That filter spec has been worked on for years and many things that are different than the [SVG 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html) have not been implemented.

In SVG 1.1 (the current cross browser baseline) - filters operate in the linearRGB space. From the SVG spec (15.1)

> (‘color-interpolation-filters’ has an initial value of linearRGB

(187, 187, 187) is what happens when you do 50% in the linearRGB space and then measure the result using an sRGB eye-dropper. In order to over-ride it, you must put color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" in your filter element.

This is a perfectly fine way to convert colors. As Robert mentioned in the comment - you can also use a flood & a composite to do it.

```
<filter id="flood-recolor">
  <feFlood flood-color="grey"/>
  <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
```